# Insert not updating sqlite table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to populate a sqlite3 table with data from a python script, but my 2nd insert always fails to update.

I have have tried calling two functions that have two separate execute many actions on the table.

```
db_file_name = 'students.db'

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file_name,)
cursor = conn.cursor()
def create_table():

    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(

                        FirstName text,
                        SurName text,
                        Class text,
                        Major text,
                        Minor text
                    );""")
    conn.commit()
```

This works just fine, I then move onto:

```
def insert_names():
    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO students(FirstName,SurName) VALUES(?, ?)"
        cursor.executemany(sql,full_names)
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print('sqlite error: ', e.args[0])
    conn.commit()

def insert_class_degree():
    try:

        sql = "INSERT INTO students(Class,Major,Minor) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
        cursor.executemany(sql,class_dept)
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print('sqlite error: ', e.args[0])


create_table()
insert_names()
insert_class_degree()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

full_names is a list of tuples:

```
[('firstname','lastname'),('firstname','lastname')]
```

class_dept is a list of tuples:

```
[('senior','art','history'),('freshman','math','biology')]
```

If I run both functions the second function doesn't insert into the database, only the first function does. I can run each function on its on and it will insert the data correctly, but when run together, the second function does not insert any data or throw an error.

I do not receive any errors, I am using sqlite studio to connect and browse the database while testing.

Comment: Thank you. I updated with clarification and examples. Even with `conn.comimt()` at the very end, it still only inserts data of one function.

Comment: Okay, it's a little better but honestly still ambiguous.  Saying the "second function **never** updates" is strong language that I would interpret literally.  However, the very next sentence makes it sound like the second function works if run alone (not never).  Instead, show exactly what works and what doesn't, and don't use "first" and "second" but the actual names of the functions.  There is nothing obviously wrong with either function... You didn't address the fact that one calls conn.commit() and not the other, but it's called in the code after the functions, so that's sufficient.

Comment: Are you certain that when browsing the database in SQLiteStudio that your views are being refreshed properly?  Honestly, I have had issues with some 3rd party DB managers handling transactions inappropriately, so I wouldn't doubt if it is not showing up-to-date data.  Also, seems strange that you have two separate functions for inserting different columns.  Even though your code should work as is, do you realize that these functions will not update the same rows?  Why would you insert names into new rows, but then insert class details into other rows (instead of using UPDATE commands)?

Comment: Thank you, I edited again for clarification. I delete the table before each new test, in SQLiteStudio. No I did not realize the functions will not update the same rows, I am looking to get the both sets of data on the same rows.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but the fact that you didn't realize that two INSERT commands create completely different rows makes me wonder what rows you are viewing or something else is amiss that isn't being shared.  A database table is not like a spreadsheet.  If you insert two rows with some columns and then insert more data in other columns, the rows do not "match up" even if there are the same number.  Instead, rows are distinguished with primary key values.  INSERT adds rows and UPDATE... updates those rows.

Comment: You likely should add a unique index for the names and/or add an explicit ID column as a primary key for identifying specific rows.  The you could call `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE id = 1` or something like `WHERE Firstname = 'John' and Surname = 'Doe'`.  But this will require passing key values along with update values in the `insert_class_degree()` function, etc.

Comment: When you insert a tuple but only specify some of the values, SQLite uses default values for the missing ones. You don’t provide any default values.

Comment: @Marichyasana  So that means Null will be inserted for the missing vlaues, especially since none of the columns have NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that, with the definitions of the two arrays (full_names and class_dept) properly positioned, all the insertions work correctly:

```
select * from students;
firstname|lastname|||
firstname|lastname|||
||senior|art|history
||freshman|math|biology
```

Since you haven't mentioned where these arrays are defined in your code, it would be reasonable to surmise that you have defined them in the wrong places.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to add a primary key to the table:

```
def create_table():
    '''
    drop table if it already exists, then create table
    '''
    conn.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students""")
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
                        ID integer not null primary key,
                        FirstName text ,
                        SurName text ,
                        Class text ,
                        Major text ,
                        Minor text,
                        unique(ID) 
                    );""")
```

Then I modified the insert_class_degree function with an update where the ID = an existing primary key:

```
def insert_class_degree():
    '''
    insert class degree into DB w/executemany
    '''
    try:


        cursor.executemany("""UPDATE students set Class = ?,Major =?, Minor = ? where ID =? """,(class_info_2))
        conn.commit()
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print('sqlite error: ', e.args[0])
```

I think I could have inserted all the columns at once, and I think that would be a preferred method.